# How to show a link to one article ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show one link to one article on my homepage in my rails app

here is the html code:

```
      <% @articles.each do |article| %> 
        <%= link_to 'Show', article %>
      <% end %>
```

here is my controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
@user = current_user
@articles = Article.all
  end

  def comics
 end
end
```

It's showing up in my home page but it shows up like this

```
show show
```

since I have two articles right now...I understand its because of the each do and its grabbing all the articles and spitting it out into my views but how do I do it so that it only shows a link to a particular article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean show a single record and not all articles?

If so just return one from the controller.

```
def home
  .....
  @article  = Article.first 
end
```

And then just   `link_to 'show', @article`

you can replace Article.first with however you want to limit to the specific article to show

Comment: so what if i wanted to show the second one or the third one or the fourth one?

Comment: Either use find,  or perhaps a where to limit what you want.  If you want the 3rd one, you can add in orders and limits to let the DB do the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

`link_to` creates a link tag of the given **name** using a URL created by the set of options. So if you change your code to look like this, provided that article responds to a method named title that returns a string:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= link_to article.title, article %>
<% end %>
```

However, `article.title` is just an example and it is perfectly fine if article doesn't have `title` method. You can use any string there which would help you identify different links.

Read the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more options.

If you wanted to show one link to of a particular article, then you could do something like this in your controller:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
```

where `article_id` comes as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific article to display you need to define an instance variable in your controller that contains a specific article, rather than all of them (`Article.all`)

```
@article = Article.first
```

or

```
@article = Article.find(id) # where id is the id of a specific article
```

Then, in your view, rather than the each block, simply have

```
<%= link_to 'Show', @article %>
```

Comment: i tried to do the @article = Article.find(id) but i get a undefined local variable or method `id'

Comment: That's why you need to replace id with an actual number that represents the id of the article.

Comment: so if the ID of an article is 2?  then i would do @article = Article.find(2)

Comment: so what if i wanted two links to an article on the same page that each leads to a seperate article?  but i dont want it to be listed...i have a slider on my page where users can slide to see the next article so i want a link on each slide that leads to an article